# I don't understand what means that "take over winter break"?

Tags: idioms

Today, I had a job interview.

Interviewer asked us that "Why are you looking for a job?"

One of my rivals answered as like

"I am looking for a job because I am trying to save money to pay for a trip that my best friend that I would like to take over winter break or when my work schedule permits."

One thing that I can't get a rough guess is "**take over winter break**".

Please describe what means that as well as whole meaning.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "that my best friend **and** I" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"take" is not part of the same expression as " over winter break": your rival is talking about **taking** a trip. When? - **over** winter break (as in **over** the weekend).

He could have inserted "the" before "winter break" but in colloquial English that is not necessary. It would have been necessary if he had wanted to take the trip "over the Winter".